# messageAuthor undefined when trying to use discord.js kick method

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

im trying to kick a member when a message is a certain text string,

i've already tried using messageAuthor to ban/kick them

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'textstring') {
    var member= messageAuthor
    memeber.kick
  }
});
```

The error states that "messageAuthor" is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't declared `messageAuthor`, so it's undefined.

The author of a message is accessible via [`Message.author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author) (returns a [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User)) and [`Message.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member) (returns a [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) if the message was sent in a guild).

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'textstring' && msg.guild && msg.member.kickable) {
    msg.member.kick('reason')
      .catch(console.error);
  }
});
```

Comment: `author` is the user that sent the message. `member` is the guild member (if message was sent on a guild) that sent the message, will be null if message was sent on DM